# Jquery Code Optimization Mouseenter Mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I just wrote some code that works very well. But I feel that it is "a little long". I think I repeat my self.

Is there a way to optimize this?

Here is the code.

```
jQuery('#content article').mouseenter(function(){
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var elHover = '#'+id+' .in_cat';
    jQuery(elHover).removeClass('hidden');
});

jQuery('#content article').mouseout(function(){
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var elHover = '#'+id+' .in_cat';
    jQuery(elHover).addClass('hidden');
});
```

cordially

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`jQuery.hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) which can assign the same handler for both enter and leave. Then use `JQuery.toggleClass` instead of `addClass`/`removeClass` or choose which action should be taken based on what `hasClass` returns.

With hover + toggleClass

```
jQuery('#content article').hover(function(){
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var elHover = '#'+id+' .in_cat';
    jQuery(elHover).toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

With hover + conditional

```
jQuery('#content article').hover(function(){
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var $elHover = jQuery('#'+id+' .in_cat');

    $elHover.hasClass('hidden') ?
        $elHover.removeClass('hidden') :
        $elHover.addClass('hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
jQuery('#content article').mouseenter(function(){
  var self = jQuery(this);
  if (self.is('.in_cat') {
    self.removeClass('hidden');
  }
}).mouseout(function(){
  var self = jQuery(this);
  if (self.is('.in_cat') {
    self.addClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript">
$('#content article').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this + '.in_cat').removeClass('hidden');
}).mouseleave(function(){
   $(this + '.in_cat').addClass('hidden')
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hover` and `this->id`:

```
$('#content article').hover(
   function() {
      $('#' . this->id . ' .in_cat').removeClass('hidden');
   },
   function() {
      $('#' . this->id . ' .in_cat').addClass('hidden');
   }
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the in-build jQuery functions for toggling the display of elements. For example (assuming you have markup similar to below):

#### HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <article id="one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        <p class="in_cat">.in_cat</p>
    </article>
    <article id="two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        <p class="in_cat">.in_cat</p>
    </article>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#content {
   border:1px dashed red;
   width:400px;
   height:100px; 
}

#one {
    color:darkblue;
}

#two {
    color:darkgreen;
}

.in_cat {
    display:none;
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
$('#content article').hover(function() {
    $('#' + this.id + ' .in_cat').toggle();
});
```

Or if you can use jQuery 1.7+

```
$('#content').on('hover', 'article', function() {
    $('#' + this.id + ' .in_cat').toggle();
});
```

Also, available in [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mnsfn/1/) form.

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML content is something like this:

```
<div id='content'>
 <article id='something'>
  <div class='in_cat'></div>
 </article>
</div>
```

then your JS code can be shortened to:

```
$('#content article').mouseenter(function()
{
 $(this).find('.in_cat').removeClass('hidden');
}).mouseout(function()
{
 $(this).find('.in_cat').addClass('hidden');
});
```

however bear in mind that the thing you want to achieve (at least what I guess is showing content on hover, hiding on mouseout) can done in pure CSS:

```
#something .in_cat {display: none}
#something:hover .in_cat {display: block !important}
```